# Would a Tiefling be able to sleep in a small fire?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

If a Tiefling made a fire that was 1 game-square in area to curl up in, could they sleep in it?

Assume that they are naked and it is a small fire.

Would the fire do any damage?

Comment: Give us more detail on the situation you're asking about. provide us with examples and some detail about the player and their character.

Comment: Why is the tiefling trying to sleep in a fire? Are they trying to get any kind of mechanical effect out of it or is it just for flavor?

Comment: Are you looking for a way this can be accomplished or asking whether a tiefling without any aid or skill, just using their racial features can do it?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: This question is on hold, however, I think I understand what you are asking. Tiefling's racial ability only grants resistance to fire, not immunity, You will still be damaged without additonal aid that grants immunity to fire.

Answer (score 5):

### They can probably indefinitely endure a very small fire, but not necessarily sleep in it

There's no general rule in the core about exactly how much damage various sizes of fire can do, but we know that being personally on fire deals 1d6 damage per round, so we can imagine that being exposed to a very small fire (such as that of a single torch) probably deals less damage than that - say 1d4 or 1d3.

Tieflings have Fire Resistance 5, so as long as a source of fire damage can only do 5 or less damage to them in a single instance, they are functionally immune to that fire - it cannot do them any damage. You could imagine that a naked tiefling could hold a torch to themselves without fear of suffering any damage or catching fire.

However, Fire Resistance is not Fire Immunity, and Fire Resistance 5 is not very much resistance. Even a very small source of fire is potentially only a couple of points of damage shy of being able to physically harm the Tiefling, and the heat of that would still be painful and distracting even if it's not quite sufficient to cause hit point damage, so I wouldn't imagine that it's realistic to sleep in those circumstances.

If the fire is sufficiently large that it can completely surround the Tiefling, that's clearly at least equivalent to being personally on fire and should deal at least 1d6 damage per round, meaning that it will sometimes overcome the Tiefling's Fire Resistance and they would (albeit perhaps slowly) take damage. The rules don't seem to support a Tiefling sleeping comfortably in a bed of fire unless they've got some other source of Fire Resistance that's much more significant.

What might be a more plausible could be a Tiefling sleeping in the *embers* of a small campfire, which would still be far too hot for a creature without Fire Resistance of some kind but should be much less damaging than an actual fire.

Comment: Well I don't know how this works really, but even if does 0 damage, the fire could be too hot to be comfortable or it would be annoying to feel it on the skin etc. Unless the character is used to it or something, I don't know the feeling of the fire on the skin... even if it does 0 damage what would the character feel?

Answer (score 2):

A very literal reading of http://www.d20srd.org/srd/environment.htm would tell us that exposure to fire only deals damage if a character's "clothes or hair" catches fire. That damage is not explicitly described as fire damage. However it's possible the character might be at risk of heatstroke, depending on whether their fire resistance counted as "a way to get cooled off".

In practice, every DM I have played with would rule that lying in a fire deals at least 1d6 fire damage per round. Tieflings only have fire resistance 5, so they would take damage roughly once per 36 seconds.

A DM might rule that a sufficiently small fire might only deal 1d4 fire damage, in which case a bald naked tiefling would be immune. Even in this case, there are no rules about what sort of distraction a character can or cannot sleep through. You'd have to ask your DM.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** 
(At least not by default.)

The 3.5 Tiefling was printed in Races Of Destiny, and does not include any fire resistance. If Little Lucy the tiefling curls up in a campfire, she will need to make reflex saves to avoid catching on fire (1d6 damage), then another reflex save each round to put the fire out and not take another 1d6 damage. I am not able to find general rules for sleeping, but would expect that to wake Lucy up.

If you are using the earlier Forgotten Realms Tiefling (which is 3.0 content, reprinted in the 3.5 Monster Manual but then overridden by Races Of Destiny), Lucy has fire resistance 5. Even with this, the fire still deals 1 point of damage every time the d6 result is “6”. As such, Lucy is awakened (on average) once every 36 seconds.

---

Of course, if it’s important to you that your character can curl up in a campfire, that’s doable. You probably only need fire resistance 6 to make that work, so you can do something goofy like taking two flaws and the feats fiendish heritage, fiendish resistance, and fiendish power (all from complete mage) at first level. That yields fire resistance 6 (plus a bunch of other minor benefits).